# Get the fill stipple of a predefined PictureFillSymbol in ArcMap

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net

In ArcMap in symbol-dialog you can choose a predefined symbol for your polygon-features, i.e. agricultural area. This is a **1 bit** picture with foreground- and background color. I grab this symbol as `IPictureFillSymbol`. It has a member `picture`, which is a `stdole.IPictureDisp`. Has anyone an idea how to access the fill pattern perhaps as hexcode or sth. else? In ArcView it was called **stipple**.

I'm in the dark.

Comment: Have you seen this article? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2007/07/30/converting-between-ipicturedisp-and-system-drawing-image/

Comment: Thanks for that, I use the  VB6 compatibility library to convert the IPictureDisp to an System.Drawing.Image/ Bitmap. That works good and is simple. Just what I needed. Then I will go through the pixels and read the stipple. When its done I will post the code, maybe someone is interested in.

Answer (score 1):

With the hint from Kirk Kuykendall I could transform the `IPictureDisp`
to a `System.Drawing.Image` with the function `VB6CompatibilityConverter.PictureDispToImage`. Then I read the BMP pixelwise into a bitfield and finally transform it into a hexcode (using the function [BinaryStringToHexString](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5612479/2747431))

Why do this? Now the stipple could be transformed back into a picture using it in another gis or in arcmap too.

```
private static string GetFillStipple(IPictureFillSymbol iSymbol)
    {
        try
        {
            stdole.IPictureDisp pd = (iSymbol as IPictureFillSymbol).Picture;
            System.Drawing.Image img = VB6CompatibilityConverter.PictureDispToImage(pd);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = img as System.Drawing.Bitmap;

            if (img.PixelFormat != System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed) return "";

            // go through the canvas and read the pixels into a bit-field
            string bits = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < bmp.Width; j++)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Color col = bmp.GetPixel(j, i);
                    bits += (col == bmp.Palette.Entries[0]) ? "1" : "0";
                }
            }

            // transfer it to a hex-code
           return string.Join(",", new string[] { BinaryStringToHexString(bits), bmp.Width.ToString(), bmp.Height.ToString() });

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```